# QAudioDecoder has ResourceError when starting

Tags: qt, qtmultimedia

I try to play a MP3 file with the QAudioDecoder->QAudioBuffer->QAudioOutput. WAV files are already working (because it does not need the QAudioDecoder).

As soon as `decoder.start()` I see there is a **QAudioDecoder::ResourceError**.

```
m_audioFormatMp3.setSampleRate(44100);
m_audioFormatMp3.setChannelCount(2);
m_audioFormatMp3.setSampleSize(32);
m_audioFormatMp3.setCodec("audio/pcm");
m_audioFormatMp3.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
m_audioFormatMp3.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

m_decoder =  new QAudioDecoder();
m_decoder->setAudioFormat(m_audioFormatMp3);
m_decoder->setSourceFilename("/home/root/test.mp3");

connect(m_decoder, &QAudioDecoder::bufferReady, this, &Audio::bufferReady);

m_decoder->start(); 
qDebug() << m_decoder->audioFormat(); // <= ERROR QAudioDecoder::ResourceError
```

Qt 5.15